# incorrect results and count coming in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to show the target reached or not category wise, im not getting proper count in submittedlinks column, submitted links count are coming wrong. the result is multiplying with no of categories assigned . actual submitted links 15. but its showing 15 * 4  i.e 60

my sample data

```
   select CatId,DayName,DayTarget,ProjectID from Tbl_DaySubmission where ProjectID='3'and DayName='FRIDAY' 

CatId   DayName DayTarget   ProjectID
35      Friday   5            3
3       Friday   4            3
6       Friday   5            3
2       Friday   15           3


select LinkId,LnkSubmsnDate,LnkSubmtdBy,ProjectId,CategoryId from tbl_Link where LnkSubmsnDate='2015-10-09'

LinkId  LnkSubmsnDate   LnkSubmtdBy ProjectId   CategoryId
147950   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147951   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147952   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147953   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147954   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147955   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147956   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147957   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147958   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147959   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147960   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147961   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147962   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147963   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147964   2015-10-09       swapna       3          2
147965   2015-10-09       swapna       3          35
```

my query

```
   SELECT
c.Categoryname
, ds.DayTarget 
, CASE WHEN (COUNT(LinkId) > 0) THEN l.LnkSubmsnDate
ELSE NULL END AS [LnkSubmsnDate]
, CASE WHEN (COUNT(LinkId) > 0) THEN l.LnkSubmtdBy
ELSE NULL END AS [LnkSubmtdBy]
, COUNT(LinkId) AS submittedLinks
, (CASE
  WHEN DayTarget=COUNT(LinkId)     THEN 'Reached'  
  WHEN DayTarget-COUNT(LinkId)   < 1  THEN 'Reached' 
  WHEN DayTarget-COUNT(LinkId)  >= 1 THEN 'Not Reached' 
END ) AS performance
FROM tbl_Category AS c
INNER JOIN Tbl_DaySubmission AS ds ON ds.CatId = c.CategoryId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_Link WHERE LnkSubmsnDate='2015-10-12' and ProjectId='109' and LnkSubmtdBy='swapna') AS l ON l.ProjectId = ds.ProjectID AND l.CategoryId = ds.CatId
WHERE ds.ProjectID = 109
GROUP BY c.Categoryname, ds.DayTarget, l.LnkSubmsnDate, l.LnkSubmtdBy
ORDER BY l.LnkSubmtdBy
```

i need output like this

```
Categoryname    DayTarget   LnkSubmsnDate   LnkSubmtdBy submittedLinks  performance
Classifieds        15          2015-10-09   swapna        15             Reached
BlogCommenting     5           2015-10-09   swapna        1            Not Reached
ForumSites         4                                                   Not Reached
Directorysites     5                                                   Not Reached
```

[image: my output]

Answer (score 0):

As you join tbl_Category and Tbl_DaySubmission and tbl_Link, it is quite likely that you count some IDs multifold.

I suppose in your case where you want to count associated links, you can simply replace

```
COUNT(LinkId)
```

with

```
COUNT(DISTINCT LinkId)
```

to get the correct number.